# Problem embedding a cgi within PHP using system

Tags: php

Hi I am using php system to embed a cgi-script like this

```
<?php echo system('./cgi-bin/rebol-include.cgi'); ?>
```

Problem is my cgi-script writes

```
print "content-type: text/html^/"
```

so that PHP will show up

```
"content-type: text/html"
```

above the html page. This is an unwanted artefact, what's the optimal way to remove it knowing a whole html page is returned from the cgi to be embedded in php ?

Comment: but why u would lik remove it ?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System can be replaced with back ticks "`" and the result of the back tick can be inserted into a substring.

So

```
<?= substr(`./cgi-bin/rebol-include.cgi`, strlen('content-type: text/html^/')) ?>
```

This should give you everything after the "content-type".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing out content within the script, return it as a string. Then echo will actually do its job.
*Also can parse whole content with **strip_tags()** or similiar if wanna get rid of HTML.*

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using virtual() instead of system() ?

> virtual() is an Apache-specific
>   function which is similar to
>    in
>   mod_include. It performs an Apache
>   sub-request. It is useful for
>   including CGI scripts or .shtml files,
>   or anything else that you would parse
>   through Apache. Note that for a CGI
>   script, the script must generate valid
>   CGI headers. At the minimum that means
>   it must generate a Content-Type
>   header.

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.virtual.php